# WWF or WPF for flowcharts?

Tags: wpf, workflow-foundation

I want to be able to present my data using a flowchart. I can use wpf to do this, but I dont want to have to code all the arrows, connectors etc - I would like to use a library if possible..

Also could I use windows workflow foundation to do this in any way? Would this help? I get the impression although WWF is workflow, its more to do with the process as opposed to presenting data.

It appears that I might have to obtain a third party control to do this....any recommendations - the component should be able to draw a flowchart at the minimum!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your not creating a work flow then stick with WPF and take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx this code project article should give you a healthy starting point for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a tool like Visio to present your data instead of creating a tool from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

WWF is not intended to *draw* anything. So it will not help anyway. Writing the drawing code yourself or finding a 3rd party library to do it is up to you. I would have chosen the latter, because once I tried to do the former. I takes a lot of time and effort to do everything right.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Visifire for charting, it's got some pretty great visuals and it's reasonably intuitive and easy to use...give it a go:

[visifire.codeplex.com](http://visifire.codeplex.com/)

Hope it helps,

Aj